# How to express two main strength without repeating words

Tags: ellipsis

I have two models. The first one put much more restriction on the connection between the variables. The second model, however, provides much more flexibility for connecting the variables.

I would like to express my sentence without repeating the words.

*Model A requires a specific connection between variables. Model B, however,  offered much more free in connecting the variables, which provides much more flexibility to the multivariate models.*

I repeat the word *much more*, which makes my sentence wordy. Can someone help me to express my sentence in a good way, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for something like:

> Model B, however, offers much more freedom in connecting the variables, hence providing enhanced flexibility to the multivariate models.